# Stuck on simple stupid C/C++ logic statement

Tags: c, boolean-logic

I have two switches that both need to be activated before I move onto the next part of my program.
Normally, either switch can be on or off. I want to run a process until both switches engage.
I seem to be unable to conceptualize the logic I need to write this statement.

I can use two statements to do what I want, such as:

```
Start_Process();

while(!sw1){    
    READ_SWITCHES();
    delay();
}

while(!sw2){    
    READ_SWITCHES();
    delay();
}

End_Process();
```

But I am sure there is a better way to do it.
My best guess so far has been this:

```
while(!(sw1 || sw2)){    
    READ_SWITCHES();
    delay();
}
```

But I am not confident that is correct.

And for some reason this doesn't look right either.

```
while(!sw1 && !sw2){
    READ_SWITCHES();
    delay();
}
```

I've done far more complicated logic statements than this, but for some reason, I am not seeing my way through this simple statement.
Thank you for any help offered.

Comment: I am trying to remember which exact class in college it was, where I learned stuff like "not (a or b)" is equivalent to "(not a) and (not b)"...

Comment: _"But I am not confident that is correct."_ Well, running and testing will approove that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: College? I'm pretty sure we learned that at school.

Comment: It could've been school. I don't remember what I ate for dinner yesterday, much less what I did 30 years ago.

Comment: I was running and testing it. That is how I found out what I was doing was not working.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You need a expression which evalualtes to `true` till one or both of the variables `sw1` and `sw2` are `false`.
Try this

```
while(!sw1 || !sw2) {

    READ_SWITCHES();
    delay();
}
```

OR

```
while(!(sw1 && sw2)) {

    READ_SWITCHES();
    delay();
}
```

Remember the expressions `!(sw1 && sw2)` and `!sw1 || !sw2` are equivalent according to De-Morgan's Law.

Comment: And these are equivalent statements in logic from Demorgan's Laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 3):

You want an OR statement:

```
while(!sw1 || !sw2){

    READ_SWITCHES();
    delay();
}
```

So this will run until BOTH become non zero (ie Both flags are set)

Answer (score 2):

I always find truth tables helpfull in these scenarios.

```
Input      Ouptut
SW1  SW2   READ_SWITCHES?
F    F     T
F    T     T
T    F     T
T    T     F
```

And then try to spot the pattern, in this case its the reverse of the AND logic so :

```
!(SW1 && SW2)
```